# How to add a comma separator to a text file in python

Tags: python, csv, text

I got a textfile with data looking like this:

```
669000 5329025 578.90
669025 5329025 578.97
669050 5329025 578.85
669075 5329025 579.04
669100 5329025 578.55
669125 5329025 578.43
669150 5329025 578.47
```

I need them comma seperated, so they look like this:

```
669000,5329025,578.90
669025,5329025,578.97
669050,5329025,578.85
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Replacing spaces with commas?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Assuming the original text file is data.txt

```
f = open('data.txt')
t = open('out.csv','w+')
t.write(f.read().replace(' ',','))
```

You will find a csv file (you can also create a txt file - just change the file extension as txt) in the current directory with the desired output

Answer (score 3):

As [@norok2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5218354/norok2) suggested:

```py
with open("text_file.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.read().replace(" ", ",")
```

```py
print(data)
```

Output:

```
669000,5329025,578.90
669025,5329025,578.97
669050,5329025,578.85
669075,5329025,579.04
669100,5329025,578.55
669125,5329025,578.43
669150,5329025,578.47
```

Answer (score 2):

```
input_file = open("path/to/textfile.txt")
output_file = open("path/to/anwer.txt", 'w')

for i in input_file:
    output_file.write(i.replace(" ", ",")

input_file.close()
output_file.close()
```

Considering you want to work with text files, you can take input from the input file, replace each space with comma in every line and subsequently write to another file.